# Where to put <style> inside SVG?

Tags: svg

Sorry if that might come an opinion-based, but I hope there's a right answer..

Where an inline CSS style should be placed inside an SVG document? In the 
example I provide below I have defined two styles and a circle that uses them.

The first style is defined inside `defs` tag and the second styles is defined right inside the `svg` tag.

Both styles are successfully displayed on the circle (at least in Chrome they do, didn't check other browsers though).

My question is which way is more standard?

I think keeping styles in `defs` keeps the whole SVG more tidy. However, one can claim that I should not use `defs` tag since no one references the style with `<use>`

Thanks!

```html
<svg height="100" width="100">
    <defs id="someDefs">
        <style id="style1">
            .blue-fill {
                fill : blue;
            }
        </style>
    </defs>
    <style id="style2">
        .red-stroke {
            stroke : red;
            stroke-width : 12
        }
    </style>
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" class="blue-fill red-stroke" />
</svg>
```

Comment: It doesn't matter.  Neither approach is "more standard".  `<style>` elements are not renderable anyway, so there is no real need to put them in the `<defs>` section.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> It doesn't matter. Neither approach is "more standard". `<style>` elements are not renderable anyway, so there is no real need to put them in the `<defs>` section

As commented by Paul LeBeau.

After reading [this article about `style` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/style), that shows an example of a style simply under the `SVG` root, I am more convinced it is correct to put `<style>` there rather than under `<defs>`.

Also, since `<defs>` tag is indeed for reusable graphical elements that should be rendered, and `<style>` is not a renderable element, there's no point keeping it there.

Answer (score 0):

Graphical elements defined in `<defs>` are not rendered directly and will be rendered only with `use`. Hence it is always a good practice to use `<defs>` if the graphical object is defined for later use. It also increases the readability of the code.

[More Information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/defs)

Comment: Yeah, but the `<style>` is not a graphical element that could be rendered, but a CSS declaration that some graphical element might use. So I guess the only remaining question is readability. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/style) the style is defined directly under the `<svg>` tag, so I think I'll follow that example and won't use `<defs>` for `<style>`

Comment: It's <defs>, not <def>

Comment: @user3567195 @Splaktar Is it really correct that the content within ``<defs>`` is rendered only with ´´use´´? I thought that one can define for example SVG gradients within ``<defs>`` and have them referenced as for example ``style="fill:url(#myGradient);"`` from all elements that want to use that gradient. The same reasoning for SVG filters.