# How to locally inject an svg file into the DOM

Tags: javascript, html, image, svg

So I need to style an svg with CSS, but it is quite large and having it in my `index.html` would be a nightmare.

I have tried [SVGInject](https://github.com/iconfu/svg-inject), [SVGInjector](https://github.com/iconic/SVGInjector), wrapping it in an `object` and using `contentDocument`, using `XMLHttpRequest`, and using the node `fs` module, but the problem is: I need to run it locally.

This is because it's something similar to a school project and there is a requirement that it has to be able to be opened from any browser and on any computer, ergo no local servers. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: `<img src="image.svg">` to load an SVG as an image

Comment: @Rojo it can't be styled with css, which is what i need

Comment: What do you mean by it can't be styled? How do you plan to style it?

Comment: You can style the SVG within the SVG code itself. See, for example, [Where to put <style> inside SVG?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44696405/215552) or [How to style SVG with external CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18434094/215552)