# Restrict CSS in .SVG file to that SVG only

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

We use Umbraco for our customers, and we want to allow them to change icons for certain content.
It's possible to upload and select a custom SVG.

Because we work on a template base, we want to control the color of the icons.
Using javascript, we transform the `<img>` with an SVG to a HTML `<svg>`-tag.
That way, we can alter the fill of stroke in the SVG's using regular CSS.

But we ran into an issue, where a customer had uploaded multiple SVG icons which were all having internal CSS and using the same class-names for paths, circles and what not.

The problem is, the last SVG that's on the page overrules the CSS for all SVG's.
For example:

```
<svg ...>
    <defs>
        <style>.a{fill: red;}</style>
    </defs>
    <circle class="a" cx="50" cy="50" r="50" />
</svg>

<svg ...>
    <defs>
        <style>.a{fill: blue;}</style>
    </defs>
    <circle class="a" cx="50" cy="50" r="50" />
</svg>
```

The customer expects a red and a blue circle, because that's what he selected within the CMS.
But this renders to 2 blue circles.

Is there any way to keep CSS found in an SVG within that same SVG?

Comment: Did you consider using a class on `svg` or style the elements with attributes? Also conside [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44743635/4728913).

Comment: Without workarounds (selectors, shadowDOM) this is not possible. The simplest way would be to use `img` tags instead of `svg`.

Comment: as part of the upload, rename all the classes.

Comment: @Lain I have altered the "<img> to <svg>" script indeed. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @JavaScript Using `img` tags don't allow me to change colors through CSS as far as I know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a hint from @Lain, I have changed the  to  script.
It now add's a random-generated classname to the SVG, and prepends that classname to every class in the  tag like this:

```
let styleTag = $svg.find('style');
if (styleTag.length) {    
    let svgClass = GenerateClassname(8);
    const regex = /\.([a-z]{1})/ig; // Get every . followed by a letter
    styleTag[0].innerHTML = styleTag[0].innerHTML.replace(regex, "." + svgClass +" .$1"); 
}
```

Comment: Since the svg get uploaded, if I understood you correctly, be aware of combined classnames like `.a.b`. I suggest looking into the current status of nesting in css3.

Comment: @Lain no nesting yet.

Comment: @Lain That's a good point. I will look in to that.

Answer (score 0):

And then, in your near future, you **do** want to style those individual elements with (global) styling.

- shadowDOM (optional part of the native [Web Components spec](https://webcomponents.today/) *aka Custom Elements*)
  was created for use-cases like these
- supported in all modern browsers
- "outside/global" CSS does not leak in
- "inside" CSS does not leak out
- and [inheritable styles](https://lamplightdev.com/blog/2019/03/26/why-is-my-web-component-inheriting-styles/), CSS properties and CSS `:part` *can* style  shadowDOM

```js
customElements.define("svg-circle", class extends HTMLElement{
  connectedCallback(){
    this.style.display = "inline-block";
    this.style.width   = "15vw";
    this.attachShadow({mode:"open"})
        .innerHTML = `<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
                        <style>.a { fill:${this.getAttribute("color")} }</style>
                        <circle              class="a" cx="50" cy="50" r="45" />
                        <circle part="inner" class="a" cx="50" cy="50" r="20" />
                      </svg>`;
  }
});
```

```html
<style>
  *::part(inner){ fill:rebeccapurple } /* higher Specificity */
</style>

<h2>Who is afraid of</h2>
<svg-circle color="red"    ></svg-circle>
<svg-circle color="yellow" ></svg-circle>
<svg-circle color="blue"   ></svg-circle>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you inject the svg into the html document, you can add a unique id to each svg and then use it in the css selector.

```html
<svg id="svg-1">
    <defs>
        <style>#svg-1 .a{fill: red;}</style>
    </defs>
    <circle class="a" cx="50" cy="50" r="50" />
</svg>

<svg id="svg-2">
    <defs>
        <style>#svg-2 .a{fill: blue;}</style>
    </defs>
    <circle class="a" cx="50" cy="50" r="50" />
</svg>
```

Comment: That's exactly the result I'm getting with the altered script. But instead of an ID, i use a class. But I get the same result.